# print 2 line above (with specific word) after a specific match pattern

Tags: python

I am newbie in python. I have a file with list of pattern and a large file with these patterns.
I want to extract lines with these patterns and two lines above these match, which has specific word.

**My big file: bigfile.txt**

> QUERY Query_17 Peptide 93 ANN2
> ENDQUERY
> 2 Query_17 Specific 197609 50 89 - 389788
> 2 Query_17 Specific 197609 50 89 - 389788
> 2 Query_17 Specific 197609 50 89 LysM - 389788
> ENDQUERY
> QUERY Query_33 Peptide 305 ANN2
> 2 Query_33 Specific 372835 33 134 GUB_WAK_bind - 45
> 2 Query_33 Non-specific 373037 222 WAK_assoc N 45
> ENDQUERY
> QUERY Query_42 Peptide 217 ANN3
> ENDQUERY
> QUERY Query_43 Peptide 435 ANN3
> 2 Query_43 Specific 237995 47 164 B_lectin - 390234
> ENDQUERY
> QUERY Query_45 Peptide 717 ANN34
> ENDQUERY
> 2 Query_45 Specific 214519 44 160 - 390234
> 2 Query_45 Specific 237995 376 449 B_lectin N 390234

**My pattern match file:**

> LysM, GUB_WAK_bind, WAK_assoc, B_lectin

**Expected output:**

> QUERY Query_17 Peptide 93 ANN2
> 2 Query_17 Specific 197609 50 89 LysM - 389788
> QUERY Query_33 Peptide 305 ANN2
> 2 Query_33 Specific 372835 33 134 GUB_WAK_bind - 45
> 2 Query_33 Non-specific 373037 222 WAK_assoc N 45
> QUERY Query_43 Peptide 435 ANN3
> 2 Query_43 Specific 237995 47 164 B_lectin - 390234
> QUERY Query_45 Peptide 717 ANN34
> 2 Query_45 Specific 237995 376 449 B_lectin N 390234

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You did provide an example but: 1. it is not minimal (it contains a lot of irrelevant information) and 2. it doesn't highlight the crux of the problem. Also, please format your code, text, etc. in a way that delineates it from the text of your question.

Comment: Hi Pierre, Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the question, hope it is more simpler.

Comment: I've been re-reading this about three times now, but I still don't get it. Are you interested in splitting the input file by `QUERY ... ENDQUERY` records? And then print the `QUERY` line along with up to two matching lines inside the record?  It would help to indicate the logic for why certain lines are in the output and some are not.

Comment: I want the lines with the pattern match and the line with "QUERY" that matches the "Query_" in the pattern match line. Example: "Query_17" is in both "QUERY" and pattern match "LysM" : QUERY Query_17 Peptide 93 ANN2: 2 Query_17 Specific 197609 50 89 LysM - 389788. ENDQUERY is not important.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

After some clarification, it seems that the original question was not formulated quite correctly. Instead, the goal is to get, for each matching line:

- the previous `QUERY` line (unless it's already been printed),
- the matching line.

Different goal --> different answer:

```py
def query_grep(file, substrings):
    lastquery = None
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line[:-1]  # remove newline
            if line.startswith('QUERY'):
                lastquery = line
            else:
                if any(s in line for s in substrings):
                    if lastquery is not None:
                        yield lastquery
                        lastquery = None
                    yield line
```

Example:

```
substrings = ['LysM', 'GUB_WAK_bind', 'WAK_assoc', 'B_lectin']

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for res in query_grep(f, substrings):
        print(res)

# or, the get whole list at once and print:
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    print('\n'.join(query_grep(f, substrings)))

# either way, the output it:
QUERY Query_17 Peptide 93 ANN2
2 Query_17 Specific 197609 50 89 LysM - 389788
QUERY Query_33 Peptide 305 ANN2
2 Query_33 Specific 372835 33 134 GUB_WAK_bind - 45
2 Query_33 Non-specific 373037 222 WAK_assoc N 45
QUERY Query_43 Peptide 435 ANN3
2 Query_43 Specific 237995 47 164 B_lectin - 390234
QUERY Query_45 Peptide 717 ANN34
2 Query_45 Specific 237995 376 449 B_lectin N 390234
```

**Original answer**

Python's [`deque`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) come in handy for this kind of things (and many, many others):

```py
# assuming you just want to look for substrings. Otherwise, use regex.
substrings = ['LysM', 'GUB_WAK_bind', 'WAK_assoc', 'B_lectin']
d = deque(maxlen=2)
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if any(s in line for s in substrings):
            print('\n'.join(d))
            print(line)
        d.append(line)
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thank you for the quick response. It works great. But i am not getting all the output. My target is the line with specific word, for above i want to print line with word "QUERY". Some times this word "QUERY" is present more than two lines above the pattern match.

Comment: that sounds like a change from your original question, which was specifically "two lines above the match plus the matching line". Please try to minimize your example to a few, well-chosen concise examples along with the desired result.